# Can we test inmobi ads without complete verification

Tags: android, inmobi

I have an android app, it is still needs testing before it can be published.I have added it as a propery but no url yet. I need to test inmobi ads for the same. Is there a way I can do so without verification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm from the InMobi team.
There is a [test mode](https://www.inmobi.com/support/art/29128996/22868557/setting-up-diagnostics-to-identify-integration-issues-and-monetization-opportunities/#settestmode) that you can use to test out ads before your app is live on the App Stores.

Comment: Thanks @Sohan, I eventually figured that out all by myself.

Comment: @Sohan: In test mode I am getting ads. Now I want to check live ads. How can I check this.?? When I am turning off global test mode "OFF", Then no ads getting served.

Comment: The fill rate must be bad. Try widening the range of ads that can be served and you will almost certainly see live ads.